# How to populate a dropdown list default value from API in Angular2 Model based form

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown

I am trying to create a Model-based form in Angular2 that includes several dropdown lists pulled in from a database, then bind the selected value to the form.  I need to be able to have the dropdown value initialized as well in the case that the form is being edited from a previously saved form.  I can't seem to find any straightforward examples of this, only examples binding selected values to a brand new Form.  Here is what I have so far:

Component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

import { Part } from '../../models/part';
import { Series } from '../../models/series';

import { PartsService } from '../../services/parts.service';
import { SeriesService } from '../../services/series.service';

@Component({
selector: 'parts',
styleUrls: ['../../../styles/main.css'],
templateUrl: './partsForm.component.html',
providers: [PartsService, SeriesService]
})

export class PartsFormComponent implements OnInit{
@Input() part: Part;
selectedPart: Part;
partsForm: FormGroup;
partName = new FormControl();
series: Series;
seriesList: Series[];
seriesSearch: string;
selectedSeries: Series = new Series();
isEdit: boolean;
selected: any;




constructor(
    private partsService: PartsService,
    private seriesService: SeriesService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
    fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
    this.partsForm = fb.group({
        partName: new FormControl(''),
        partLength: new FormControl(''),
        seriesId: new FormControl(''),
});
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    let partId: string;

    this.route.params
        .subscribe((params: Params) => partId = params['id']);

    this.isEdit = (partId != undefined && partId.substring(0, 1) !== "T");

    if (this.isEdit) {
        this.partsService.getPartById(+partId).subscribe(part => this.part = part);
    }  else {
        this.part = new Part;
    }

    this.getSeriesList();
}

intializePartForm() {
    this.series.seriesId = this.part.seriesId;

}

getSeriesList() {
    this.seriesService.getAllSeries().subscribe(data => this.seriesList = data);
}

saveNew() {
    this.part.partId = 0;
    this.savePart();
}

savePart() {
    this.part.seriesId = this.selectedSeries.seriesId;

    this.partsService.savePart(this.part).subscribe(data => this.part = data);
}
}
```

HTML Template:

```
<form  *ngIf="part" [formGroup]="partsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
    <div class="col-lg-6">        
        <div class="form-group" >
            <label>Part Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName="partName" placeholder="Part Name" [value]="part.partName" [disabled]="isEdit">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <label>Series</label>
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="series"> 
                <option *ngFor="let series of seriesList" [selected]="series.seriesId == part.seriesId" >{{series.seriesName}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Part Length</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control"  formControlName="partLength" placeholder="Part Length" >
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!isEdit">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="saveNew()" >Save As New</button>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="isEdit">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="savePart()" >Save Changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Models
Series

```
export class Series {
    seriesId: number;
    seriesName: string;   
}
```

Part

```
export class Part {
        partId: number;
        partName: string;
        partLength: number;
        seriesId: number;
        seriesName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reactive forms, things like `[selected]` and `[disabled]` do not work, you need to use `patchValue` (or `setValue`) and toggle the enable and disable of field in another way.

After you have received aaall your data that you need, patch the form values with what you want. For instance, after you have gotten the values for your list, call a function to set the values, here named `patchForm()`:

```
getSeriesList() {
  this.seriesService.getAllSeries().subscribe(data => {
    this.seriesList = data;
    // call method here to set values
    this.patchForm();
  });
}
```

and the function to set default values could look like this. You just apply the logic you need instead of the following values.

```
patchForm() {
  this.partsForm.patchValue({
    partName: this.part.partName
    series: this.seriesList[1].seriesName
  })  
}
```

As mentioned `[disabled]` won't work in your form (like you are trying on the `partName` form control), you'd need to toggle the enabled and disabled in another way. That can be achieved with the following method:

```
toggleDisableEnable() {
  let control = this.partsForm.get('partName')
  control.enabled ? control.disable() : control.enable();
}
```

Finally, a...

### [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YnhNONIWnW2tXzwrat5r?p=preview)

...to tinker with to help you with your form :) Some logic like in the patchValue you need to set up yourself, just gave you an example on how to do this, as well as the disabling and enabling of a field.